# Devise logouts all signed in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have Admin and User models. When I'am signed in both main site and admin panel and click logout at control panel or main site, devise kills both session. Any solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, devise logs out all logged in scopes on session destroy.  You can override this easily in the initializer

```
app_name/config/initializers/devise.rb
```

Change:

```
config.sign_out_all_scopes = true
```

to false

```
config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```